Nyquist plot stability analysis
I'm a bit confused with the stability analysis using Nyquist plots. Suppose I have the following open loop transfer function:
$G(s) = \frac{s-1}{s^2(s+2)^2}$
I want to make a stability analysis under unity negative feedback. When I sketch the Nyquist plot for this transfer function, when the gain is unity, there is no encirclement of $-1$. Since there is also no open loop poles that are encircled with the Nyquist path, I can conclude that the system is stable. However, if you plot root locus for this example, we see that there will be always a portion of the locus in the right half plane, so for any gain $K$, the system will be unstable.
The reason behind my confusion is that the Nyquist criteria does not consider open loop zeros in its stability criteria. Can you clarify that?

As a graphical comment, follows the Nyquist plot for $\frac{s-1}{s^2(s+2)^2}$


One has to be careful when drawing a Nyquist plot for systems that have poles on the imaginary axis. Namely, the plot is not well defined at those poles and no immediate conclusion can be drawn about stability. To circumvent this issue one can move the Nyquist contour a small amount near the poles on the imaginary axis, such that the poles on the imaginary axis fall either in- or outside of the contour, and therefore also do or don't count towards the number of unstable open loop poles. For example one such way that this can be done is demonstrated in the image below${}^\text{[1]}$


Another way of moving the Nyquist contour away from the poles on the imaginary axis is instead of $s=j\omega$ to use $s=j\omega+\delta$ with $\delta$ a small constant for the Nyquist contour. The value of $\delta$ should be chosen such that none of the (open loop) poles that don't lie on the imaginary axis cross the Nyquist contour boundary. Though, this crossing check on the location of all poles for things like delays this might be hard to check, in which case the initially mentioned method could still be used.
Another important thing to note is that shifting the Nyquist contour also changes whether the closed loop poles are "considered" stable or unstable. Namely, the Nyquist stability criterion, $Z=N+P$, only tells you about the number of closed loop poles inside the considered Nyquist contour, $Z$, given the number of clockwise encirclements of the minus on point, $N$, and the number open loop poles inside the considered Nyquist contour, $P$. So when using any mismatch between the actual unstable region, the right half plane, and the actually used Nyquist contour one does have to be more careful drawing closed loop stability conclusions, especially for systems close to instability.

The first method of dealing with open loop poles on the imaginary axis is usually preferred because it has less caveats. However, for the second method it is easier to generate plots and it still can help to illustrate the idea behind it. In the sections below I will demonstrate both a positive and negative value for $\delta$ for your system below.

For example using $\delta=0.1$ yields that none of the open loop poles lie inside the shifted Nyquist contour ($P=0$) and has the following Nyquist plot:

This has one clockwise encirclement of -1 ($N=1$), so the number of unstable closed loop poles is 1 ($Z=N+P$).

For example using $\delta=-0.1$ yields that the two open loop poles at the origin lie inside the shifted Nyquist contour ($P=2$) and has the following Nyquist plot:

This has one counterclockwise encirclement of -1 ($N=-1$), so the number of unstable closed loop poles is also 1 ($Z=N+P$).

As mentioned before one does have to be careful about choosing a $\delta$ close enough to zero, such that the reported number of "unstable" closed loop poles, $Z$, does actually tell you the poles in the right half plane.
In this case it can be shown that under unitary negative feedback the closed loop has poles are located at -2.7106, 0.34509 and -0.81722±0.63340i. So the correct conclusion can in this case be drawn for $-0.81722>\delta>0$ or $0>\delta>0.34509$. For example using $\delta=-0.82$ or $\delta=0.35$ would yield an incorrect conclusion.
When using this Nyquist contour offset method it is recommended to use both a positive and negative value for $\delta$ and only if both yield to same number of closed loop unstable poles ($Z=N+P$) can one draw a conclusion about the closed loop stability. If there is a difference between the obtained number closed loop unstable poles from the positive and negative value for $\delta$, then you have to choose values for $\delta$ closer to zero. Though, this does still tell you that there are closed loop poles in the band defined by the positive and negative value used for $\delta$ around the imaginary axis, but not whether they are stable.

[1] Alavi, S. M., & Saif, M. (2015). On stability analysis by using Nyquist and Nichols Charts. arXiv preprint arXiv:1511.04752.

This concept is also nicely demonstrated in the following video.

It would be important to explain why does $\delta=0.4$ yield an incorrect solution and how to know beforehand whether $\delta$ is close enough and yields the correct solution.

@KBS Good point. I have updated my answer.

@KBS but knowing before hand would imply knowing the closedloop poles already, which kind of defeats a big part of using a Nyquist plot. One could of course use both a small positive and negative offset for $\delta$ and check if both yield the same $Z$.

Yes, this is my problem as one cannot know beforehand what offset would be acceptable as it depends on the closed-loop poles which we want to prove the stability. This is a circular argument. In this regard it would be preferable to pick a contour that just goes around the poles on the imaginary axis.
